# How to use CCCrypt() to encrypt a file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

when I encrypt a file(doc, pdf, etc.), I use:

```
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;    
CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                 keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                 NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                 dataBytes, dataLength, /* input */
                                 buffer, bufferSize,/* output */
                                 &numBytesEncrypted );
```

when decrypt, I use:

```
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,    kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                 keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                 NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                 dataBytes, dataLength,/* input */
                                 buffer, bufferSize,/* output */
                                 &numBytesEncrypted );
```

But when decrypt, it returns error:kCCDecodeError = -4304.

If I remove the param of kCCOptionPKCS7Padding when decrypt, there is no error. But the file cannot open either.

So, could u tell me how to pass these params?

thanks alot!

Answer (score 4):

This for encryption

```
    NSString *key =@"YourKey";
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char *dataIn = "This is your data";
    char dataOut[500];// set it acc ur data
    bzero(dataOut, sizeof(dataOut));
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

    CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,  keyPtr,kCCKeySizeAES256, NULL, dataIn, strlen(dataIn), dataOut, sizeof(dataOut), &numBytesEncrypted);
```

this is for decryption

```
char dataOut2[500];
bzero(dataOut2, sizeof(dataOut2));
size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;   

CCCryptorStatus result = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, keyPtr,kCCKeySizeAES256, NULL, dataOut, numBytesEncrypted, dataOut2, sizeof(dataOut2), &numBytesDecrypted);
```

Comment: you don't check CCCryptorStatus when you encrypt. Are you sure it works? Also, how to you create "buffer". Is it based on bufferSize?

Comment: Deriving a key from a string via NSString is quite a tricky process. Because a char byte usually has lots of leading zero and putting a lot of zeros in your AES key. IOS provides a decent key derivation algorithm as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569555/pbkdf2-using-commoncrypto-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
bzero(dataOut, sizeof(dataOut2));
```

to

```
bzero(dataOut2, sizeof(dataOut2));
```

Thanks Inder

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it! Have also tested it successfully. The line should be:

```
CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, keyPtr,kCCKeySizeAES256, NULL, dataOut, numBytesEncrypted, dataOut2, sizeof(dataOut2), &numBytesDecrypted);
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please share the full code. i am also trying the file encryption and decryption. Whats dataIn and dataout here. its file path?. how to test in ios device. I am totally new in ios. Please help me. Thanks