# PBKDF2 using CommonCrypto on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, pbkdf2, commoncrypto

I'm trying to use `CommonCrypto` to generate keys using `PBKDF2` but I can't seem to import `CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h`, I just errors that it is not found.

Any ideas?

edit: I should probably mention I have already added the security framework and I can import all of the other `CommonCrypto` headers.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's how i generate AES256 keys. The only interesting this is that i get CommonCrypto to estimate for me how many rounds to use. It seems pretty straightforwards.

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h>

...

// Makes a random 256-bit salt
- (NSData*)generateSalt256 {
    unsigned char salt[32];
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
        salt[i] = (unsigned char)arc4random();
    }
    return [NSData dataWithBytes:salt length:32];
}

...

// Make keys!
NSString* myPass = @"MyPassword1234";
NSData* myPassData = [myPass dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData* salt = [self generateSalt256];

// How many rounds to use so that it takes 0.1s ?
int rounds = CCCalibratePBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, myPassData.length, salt.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256, 32, 100);

// Open CommonKeyDerivation.h for help
unsigned char key[32];
CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, myPassData.bytes, myPassData.length, salt.bytes, salt.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256, rounds, key, 32);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that PBKDF calibration may be OK if you only need to derive a key on one device (or at least the same class of devices). When you e.g. need to sync data and derive the same key on different devices, then it’s a more sensible approach to set a number of rounds that will work painlessly on all devices (e.g. Mac Pro & iPhone). Something between 10000–20000 should be a good number in 2012.

Comment: It's better to use SecRandomCopyBytes() for pseudo-random number generation in cryptography applications. - Otherwise, great code! I like the PBKDF2 round estimation bit =)

Comment: Is it necessary to create a salt of length 32 bytes ?

Comment: Hi @PiyushKashyap, a 256-bit salt ensures maximum entropy for a 256-bit key. Regardless, it is completely unnecessary. 128-bits is more than enough, and 64-bits is enough.

Answer (score 7):

1. Add this library to your project libcommonCrypto.dylib
2. #import  into hash key generation class.
3. use following code to generate hash key.

This is the code what i have used:

```
// Salt data getting from salt string.
NSData *saltData = [@"Salt String" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Data of String to generate Hash key(hexa decimal string).
NSData *passwordData = [@"Hash key generated string" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Hash key (hexa decimal) string data length.
NSMutableData *hashKeyData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

// Key Derivation using PBKDF2 algorithm.
int result = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2, passwordData.bytes, passwordData.length, saltData.bytes, saltData.length, kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1, 1000, hashKeyData.mutableBytes, hashKeyData.length);

// Hexa decimal or hash key string from hash key data.
NSString *hexDecimalString = hashKeyData.description;

NSLog(@"Hexa decimal string:%@", hexDecimalString);
```

Comment: Great, just update. You don't need to add libcommonCrypto.dylib to project in iOS8

Comment: Don't use .description for data-to-string converting.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building for iOS5 ? or earlier versions ?

Both API, `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF` and `CCCalibratePBKDF`, defined in the header file are only available on IOS5 (or OSX 10.7) and later.

You can make sure the file exists by executing this inside a terminal window:

```
$ find /Developer/ -name CommonKeyDerivation.h
/Developer//Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h
/Developer//Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h
/Developer//SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonKeyDerivation.h
```

Comment: iOS 4 unfortunately. Guess I will look for an alternative implementation then.