# CommonCrypto alternative to PBKDF2

Tags: iphone, ios, security, pbkdf2, commoncrypto

Since Apple has deprecated the use of openSSL in iOS I need an alternative to PBKDF2 in one of iOS Security frameworks. I tried to search CommonCrypto with no luck.

Is there a fair alternative to PBKDF2 which is recommanded by Apple?
i.e.  key derivation function (password based) in iOS (implemented by Apple)?

P.S. I'm aware of [PBKDF2 using CommonCrypto on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569555/pbkdf2-using-commoncrypto-on-ios) , I don't want to use openSSL since it is not recommanded by Apple, see [Why is Apple Deprecating OpenSSL in MacOS 10.7 (Lion)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406946/why-is-apple-depricating-openssl-in-macos-10-7-lion)

Answer (score 3):

PBKDF2 is a standard algorithm and is the recommended PBKDF algorithm. It is not "OpenSSL" and is not deprecated (it is encouraged). You should be using `CCKeyDerivationPBKDF()` from CommonCrypto for this purpose in iOS 5+ and OS X 10.7+. If you want to backport this version of CommonCrypto to older platforms, see [How to compile and use CommonCrypto for iOS 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958661/how-to-compile-and-use-commoncrypto-for-ios-4).