# php + ios encrypt and decrypt 3des + base64

Tags: php, ios, base64, encryption, 3des

i need encrypt and decrypt with php a string code generated by that ios method explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9479657/721253

for encrypt with php i use that script

```
$key = 'f968f8e82961489a8b14b345';
$data = 'odio quando sto studiando e un velociraptor mi lancia addosso banane';
$encrypted = null;
$m = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_3DES, null, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, null);
$fake_iv = str_repeat(chr(0), mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($m));
mcrypt_generic_init($m, $key, $fake_iv);
$encrypted = mcrypt_generic($m, $data);
die(base64_encode($encrypted));
```

and on IOs for decript i use that

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://oscurodrago.it/tools/crypto.php"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSData *outData = [self TripleDES:data encryptOrDecrypt:kCCDecrypt key:@"f968f8e82961489a8b14b345"];
```

ccStatus return decode error   ->  if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) NSLog( @"DECODE ERROR");

**update**
that is viewcontroller.m where i'm testing that script

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import "GTMBase64.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSData*)TripleDES:(NSData*)plainData encryptOrDecrypt:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt key:(NSString*)key {

    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;

    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {
        NSData *EncryptData = [GTMBase64 decodeData:plainData];
        plainTextBufferSize = [EncryptData length];
        vplainText = [EncryptData bytes];
    }
    else
    {
        plainTextBufferSize = [plainData length];
        vplainText = (const void *)[plainData bytes];
    }

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    // uint8_t ivkCCBlockSize3DES;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);
    // memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

    //    NSString *key = @"123456789012345678901234";
    NSString *initVec = @"init Vec";
    const void *vkey = (const void *) [key UTF8String];
    const void *vinitVec = (const void *) [initVec UTF8String];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(encryptOrDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       vkey, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                       kCCKeySize3DES,
                       vinitVec, //"init Vec", //iv,
                       vplainText, //"Your Name", //plainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       &movedBytes);
    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess) NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    else if (ccStatus == kCCParamError) NSLog( @"PARAM ERROR");
     else if (ccStatus == kCCBufferTooSmall) NSLog( @"BUFFER TOO SMALL");
     else if (ccStatus == kCCMemoryFailure) NSLog( @"MEMORY FAILURE");
     else if (ccStatus == kCCAlignmentError) NSLog( @"ALIGNMENT");
     else if (ccStatus == kCCDecodeError) NSLog( @"DECODE ERROR");
     else if (ccStatus == kCCUnimplemented) NSLog( @"UNIMPLEMENTED");

    NSData *result;

    if (encryptOrDecrypt == kCCDecrypt)
    {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
    }
    else
    {
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
        result = [GTMBase64 encodeData:myData];
    }

    return result;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.oscurodrago.it/tools/crypto.php"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSData *outData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[self TripleDES:data encryptOrDecrypt:kCCDecrypt key:@"f968f8e82961489a8b14b345"]];

    NSLog(@"%@", data );

    // NSData *encriptdata = [self TripleDES:data encryptOrDecrypt:kCCEncrypt key:@"f968f8e82961489a8b14b345"];

    NSLog(@"%@", [outData length] );
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the 'outData' to base64 encoded string. Then only you can print the NSData. Try before that, data is not empty by printing the 'outData' length by

```
NSLog(@"%d",[outData length]);
```

See [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sag333ar/files/NSStringAdditions/NSStrinAdditions.h.zip/download) link for converting NSData to base64 string.

Comment: i'm not very good with ios but `[outData length]` return 0 and i tought http://stackoverflow.com/a/9479657/721253 already decrypt/encrypt base64

Comment: What did you get when printed NSLog(@"%d",[data length]); If this too 0 you are not getting any data from server.

Comment: that is stamp of NSLog(@"%@",data); dosen't seem enpity
2012-03-22 18:06:38.973 Cryptdata[1012:f803] <39744d56 306b6a38 716d6e4e 44726f44 414a584c 36355777 34517676 6c6d6339 64566c56 42533973 7038306f 63796e69 75797979 425a6d4b 5377472f 7358706e 5a724546 38356f52 4b7a5269 38683639 65737a4c 476d6c65 78563048 524b3337>